# Merging records based on a time difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (id int, name varchar(255), startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:00:00.000','2011-01-11 00:01:10.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:00:20.000','2011-01-11 00:01:50.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:01:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:50.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 'Adam', '2011-01-11 00:00:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:20.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5, 'Adam', '2011-01-11 00:00:10.000','2011-01-11 00:01:30.000')

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

I am trying to merge all records with the same name within a range of 60 seconds to each other to get the following:

```
John 2011-01-11 00:00:00.000 2011-01-11 00:01:10.000
John 2011-01-11 00:01:40.000 2011-01-11 00:01:50.000
Adam 2011-01-11 00:00:10.000 2011-01-11 00:01:20.000
```

Any suggestions on how to do this on a table with about 50K records? Currently, I managed to get to this:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #Merge(id1 int, id2 int)

INSERT INTO #Merge
SELECT id, uuid
FROM
(
    SELECT t.id, u.uuid, t.name, t.startdate, t.enddate, u.ustartdate, u.uenddate,
           (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(second, t.startdate, u.ustartdate) <= 60 AND DATEDIFF(second, t.startdate, u.ustartdate) >= 0) then 1 else 0 END) Flag
    FROM #Temp t 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id AS uuid, name, startdate AS ustartdate, enddate AS uenddate
    FROM #Temp) u 
    ON t.name = u.name AND t.startdate != u.ustartdate AND t.id != u.uuid
) w
WHERE Flag = 1

SELECT * FROM #Merge

-- Insert non-mergable records
CREATE TABLE #TEMP2 (id int, name varchar(255), membergroup varchar(255), startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
INSERT INTO #TEMP2
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id1 FROM #Merge UNION SELECT id2 FROM #Merge)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
```

Of course, I am not sure how to proceed from here. The `#Merge` table gives me rows that are to be merged. What I did was to insert non-mergable rows first into #Temp2 first.

**EDIT:**

Updated set of rows, just in case:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'John', 'A', '2011-01-11 00:00:00.000','2011-01-11 00:01:10.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'John', 'A', '2011-01-11 00:00:01.000','2011-01-11 00:01:10.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 'John', 'B', '2011-01-11 00:00:20.000','2011-01-11 00:01:50.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 'John', 'C', '2011-01-11 00:01:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:50.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5, 'John', 'C', '2011-01-11 00:01:50.000','2011-01-11 00:02:20.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(6, 'Adam', 'A', '2011-01-11 00:00:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:20.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(7, 'Adam', 'B', '2011-01-11 00:00:10.000','2011-01-11 00:01:30.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(8, 'Adam', 'B', '2011-01-11 00:03:10.000','2011-01-11 00:04:30.000')
```

Comment: The answer will depend on how large, and what indexes you have and/or can afford to add... Also what range of dates/times you're dealing with (is this a very large set of users in a small time-range, or very spread-out? In other words, one-time process or ougoing high-volume requirement?) Finally, we also need to know how you would want to handle the case of 3 records created 40 seconds apart (1st and 3rd in different 60-second ranges, but 2nd matches both), and 3 records 15 seconds apart (all three fall within a single 60-second range)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually, the table is not so big. It has about 50K records so I can add an index on any required columns. From what I see, the data is spread-out. Within a time interval, I am expecting 2-3 records to merge. If its not too difficult, I was thinking of merging all the records in both the cases.

Comment: Do you want "<60 seconds between rows" or "assign rows to fixed 60 second intervals"? The latter is easier but means rows at 59 and 01 seconds are in different intervals, Also, what is the unique key per row?

Comment: Oh.. Actually, I want <60 seconds between rows of the same name. Currently the table has no unique key but I guess I can add a column of row numbers as its primary key. Update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Another one: what is the 60 second criteria? Why does John, C get into the output when comparing startdates only (as per your example)

Comment: Actually, that membergroup is not relevant for this example. Sorry! I must've accidentally copied it from my IDE. I did manage to form another table (my edit above) that tells me what all rows are to be merged. The only thing I am trying to figure out now is to iterate through this and merge all the rows in the original table somehow. I am pretty sure this must be the 'dumb' approach.

Comment: It can be done: but you need to explain how the rows should be compared. Again: "what is the 60 second criteria"? I uses John,C to highlight your desired output row

Comment: I have a few listeners in my system who can be off by a few seconds. The 60 seconds accounts for any delays in a log record sent to me. The actual 60 is a bit arbitrary. Once I figure this out, I will have to experiment with a few other values. I will see if I can clarify more without confusing myself: I want to merge all rows whose startdates are within a 60 second interval with each other. When merging, I want to take the earliest start and end dates.

Comment: @Legend let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2088/discussion-between-gbn-and-legend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below manage's to show both merged rows (rows 1-2,4-5) and unique rows (row 3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.name,a.startdate,a.enddate
FROM temp a
  LEFT JOIN temp b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id < b.id AND DATEDIFF(s,a.startdate,b.startdate)<=60
  LEFT JOIN temp c ON c.name = a.name AND c.id < a.id AND DATEDIFF(s,c.startdate,a.startdate)<=60
WHERE (b.id IS NOT NULL OR c.id IS NULL) AND a.id <= COALESCE(c.id,a.id)
```

[image]

Comment: @Legend it would be nice for me to know if it works(curiosity). Works fine with sample data.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. I tried it. While it seems to be working, there are some duplicate rows (which can be fixed) but there is a different problem. Please see my updated test set. It outputs `2011-01-11 00:00:01.000` without merging it. Not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: I find it challenging and always want to improve my coding. I ll check it out.

Comment: If you have time give it one more try :)

Comment: Hmm... Bulleye! Works perfect. The only problem I was facing is that it takes about 6:40 minutes on a table with 50K records despite adding  all possible indices. Not sure if this is an artifact with the query. I added the execution plan to your answer. Thank you once again. I will accept this as the answer due to its simplicity.

Comment: You have 50k rows total or per date? How about storing result's each day in an another table and run the queries against it?

Comment: Oh.. its the entire table. This data is for the last 6 years so storing each day in a different table would prove rather heavy I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Given you haven't said how to use the 60 second interval and your sample code showed only a startdate comparison, here you go

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Temp t1
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1*
    FROM #Temp t2
    WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND DATEDIFF(second, t1.startdate, t2.startdate) < 60 AND t1.id < t2.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    ) t2x
```

Based on startdate only, row pairs 1/2 and 4/5 make it into the output. Row 3 doesn't so you'll have to explain why you added it.

That is, row id = 3 is *not* within 60 seconds of row 1 or 2 based on startdate. So it shouldn't be in the output.

This assumes that id and startdate are both increasing.

Edit, after chat:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Temp t1
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #Temp t2
    WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND DATEDIFF(second, t1.startdate, t2.startdate) < 60 AND t1.id < t2.id
    ORDER BY t2.id DESC
    ) t2x
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t1.*, t1.*
FROM
    #Temp t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        t1ZZ.id, t2xZZ.id
    FROM
        #Temp t1ZZ
        CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM #Temp t2ZZ
        WHERE t1ZZ.name = t2ZZ.name AND DATEDIFF(second, t1ZZ.startdate, t2ZZ.startdate) < 60 AND t1ZZ.id < t2ZZ.id
        ORDER BY t2ZZ.id DESC
        ) t2xZZ
     WHERE
        t1.id IN (t1ZZ.id, t2xZZ.id)
)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. Actually, Row 3 did make it to the output. It is Row 1 and Row 2 that got merged. In the result, the first row is the result of merging Rows 1 and 2 from the original table. Min(startdate), Min(enddate) for both rows form the values for Row 1 of the final table.